# Не меняется тип анимации при удалении ячейки

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, анимация

Пытаюсь задать тип анимации удаления ячейки из таблицы при помощи deleteRowsAtIndexPaths withRowAnimation. Анимация появляется, но независимо от переданного типа, она всегда одинаковая. Ячейка сжимается вверх и исчезает. Метод loadData обновляет массив с данными для заполнения таблицы.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [[_coreData managedObjectContext] deleteObject:[_notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [_coreData saveData];
    [self loadData];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: Возможно, нужно добавить beginUpdates и endUpdates. Никогда не вызывал анимированное обновление таблицы вне этих методов.

Comment: Пробовал - не помогает. Насколько я понял из документации, внутри них нужно прописывать анимацию, которая должна идти одновременно.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать тестовый проект, без вашей бизнес логики, если в нём не справится добавьте здесь  на него ссылку. Если исправится, ищите отличия.

Comment: Проверьте, не вызывается ли у Вас другой метод делегата в один момент с анимацией. Например попробуйте сначала удалить ячейку, затем изменять модель.

Comment: Сделал голый проект с navigation controller'ом. Вообщем если удалять ячейки через штатную кнопку Edit в навигейшн баре, т.е. появляются красные кружки, по нажатию на которые справа от ячейки выдвигается красная кнопка Delete, то анимация всегда только такая, как я описывал. А если производить удаление другим способом, допустим, вызывая селектор с задержкой или по нажатию на ячейку, то все работает как должно. Думаю анимация с выдвижной кнопкой Delete сбивает анимацию ячейки, или программно задано, что в таком случае только один тип анимации. Это можно как-то обойти?

Comment: А как насчёт вызова удаления, после того, как анимация выдвижения завершится (отложено, время можно подобрать или поискать где-либо его)?